# Incompatible pointer type error when compiling Linux block driver init_request function

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I am writing a Linux block driver. I have been using another one as a reference
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/drivers/block/mtip32xx/mtip32xx.c#L2382

I am having an issue with the init_request function of the blk_mq_ops structure:

```
static struct blk_mq_ops mydrv_mq_ops = {
    .queue_rq = mydrv_queue_rq,
    .init_request   = mydrv_init_cmd,
};
```

My function is :

```
int mydrv_init_cmd(void *data, struct request *rq, unsigned int hctx_idx, unsigned int request_idx, unsigned int numa_node)
{
    struct mydrv_cmd *cmd = blk_mq_rq_to_pdu(rq);

    sg_init_table(cmd->sg, REQ_MAX_SEG);
}
```

But when I compile it I get an error :

> ../mydrv.c: At top level:
>
> ../mydrv.c:344:18: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
>
> .init_request = mydrv_init_cmd,
>
> mydrv.c:344:18: note: (near initialization for 'mydrv_mq_ops.init_request')

I can't work out what the problem is as my function is just lifted from the reference one. How can I resolve this compiler error?

Comment: I've made a few edits to your question: I added the C tag so syntax highlighting works in code blocks, changed the error message block to a quote so the syntax highlighting isn't applied, rephrased the question at the end so it isn't a simple "yes" or "no" question, and rephrased the title a bit to more accurately summarize the question. I left the vertical bar and the "^~~..." in the error message because I didn't know if they actually appeared in the error output. Consider removing them if they weren't actually printed.

Answer (score 0):

The example you've borrowed from has the `init_request` function defined as a `static` function. You probably need to make your function `static` as well to reference it from a `static struct`:

```
static int mydrv_init_cmd(void *data, struct request *rq, unsigned int hctx_idx, unsigned int request_idx, unsigned int numa_node)
```

Comment: I tried it as static but didn't make any difference. I also realized that I forgot to add the return statement. But again still errors out. I just cant understand what the problem is.

Comment: @jb2019 That's a bummer. Try adding the compiler argument **-Wall** to enable all warnings. That might give you a hint. Also, ensure the function is defined before the struct definition, or at least a function prototype.

Comment: @jb2019 Also, keep in mind that compiler errors don't necessarily tell you where errors *occurred*, they tell you where an error was *detected*. So the problem might not actually be where the compiler is pointing. When you can't find a problem on the line the compiler is blaming, start working your way back up through the lines of the file, looking for unclosed parentheses, missing commas and semicolons, or anything else out of place that could be left unresolved from a previous line.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I am beginning to think the error must be somewhere else. Do I just add the -Wall to the makefile?